# Best Solution Exchange member list

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

We would like every one to have an e-mail member list of external customers (to be BCC'ed) but that list may need to be modified in the future at any given notice. It would be preferable for this list to be contained within MSOutlook, and without the need to distribute local copies every time a change is made.  Is this possible within the GAL considering these customers are external (they don't have AD accounts).  Are there any alternate solutions?

Comment: We certainly have addresses in our GAL that do not have AD accounts. They're just in a custom list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to serverfault, as it's about configuring business server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new AD group (distribution list), and populate it with external addresses, which will appear in the GAL.

Comment: How is this possible, so far I found only solutions that do require admin privileges on Exchange, something that normal mortals cannot get on real corporate environments.